# Could not create simulator with name and runtime id

Tags: appium, appium-desktop

I use Xcode 10.1 and with Appium Desktop my capability is

```
{
  "uuid": "B13D4F22-AA4E-4890-8C2B-3C5B7B6E3678",
  "bundleId": "com.slacorp.eptt",
  "platformName": "iOS",
  "deviceName": "iPhone 8",
  "automationName": "XCUITest"
}
```

but when I run Appium Desktop I get

> An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not create simulator with name 'appiumTest-iPhone 8', device type id 'iPhone 8' and runtime id 'undefined'. Reason: 'simctl error running 'create': Invalid runtime: undefined'

Comment: Which appium version are you using? Try to use the latest appium version. Earlier i had the similar problem, i am not sure how i solved it. Also make sure you are using valid **udid**

Comment: . Also please check the full appium server log.

Comment: have you found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Udid capability is missing: "udid": auto